# MongoDB FULLTEXT Search for Emails

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

Let's say I have the following fields in collection
fname,
lname,
contactData

sample:

1. fname = Dmitry
2. lname = Semenov
3. contactData = 9491001120  9492006839 dmitry@domain.com dima@domain.com

is it possible to implement FULLTEXT search on such collection so for example I can find by
Dmitry & dima@domain.com?

Comment: "The text search is currently a beta feature": http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially yes.

1. [Enable text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/) for your mongodb instance: `mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true`
2. [Create a fulltext index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index) for [the fields you want to search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/) on, e.g.
   `db.emails.ensureIndex( { fname: "text", lname: "text", contactData: "text" } )`
3. [perform a text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/text/#dbcmd.text) to find the relevant documents, e.g. `db.emails.runCommand("text", { search: "Dmitry", language: "none" });`

Since you're indexing names and email addresses, it's probably helpful to set `language` to `none`, otherwise stemming and stop words will be used.

Using search: "Dmitry dmitry@domain.com" would look for documents with either Dmitry OR dmitry@domain.com in any of the fields, I don't think there's a way to use AND currently.